# How to get unique elements in numpy array with different number of elements in each array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wants to get unique in numpy 2D array but the array is like this:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3], [1]])
np.unique(a)
```

So, the array have different number of elements and I wanted the flatten array with unique elements like this:

```
[1,2,3]
```

But "np.unique" not working as expected.

Comment: It's not a 2d array.  It's a 1d array of lists (look at `shape` and `dtype`).

Answer (score 5):

You have an **object** type array due to the different lengths of inner lists, `np.unique` will compare objects (inner lists) against each other instead of the elements; You need to manually flatten the array using `np.concatenate` in a 1d array and then use `np.unique`:

```
np.unique(np.concatenate(a))
# array([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to flatten the list using `itertools.chain` and then use `np.unique()`. This can be faster than `np.concatenate()` if you have a very large list.

For example, consider the following:

First generate random data:

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 100000
a = np.array(
    [[np.random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(np.random.randint(0,10))] for _ in range(N)]
)
```

Timing results:

```
%%timeit
np.unique(list(chain.from_iterable(a)))
#10 loops, best of 3: 66.7 ms per loop

%%timeit
np.unique(np.concatenate(a))
#10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop
```

---

You could also use [`pandas.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.unique.html), which according to the docs:

> Significantly faster than numpy.unique. Includes NA values.

```
%%timeit
pd.unique(np.concatenate(a))
#10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop

%%timeit
pd.unique(list(chain.from_iterable(a)))
#10 loops, best of 3: 57.2 ms per loop
```